# Delay between printing characters in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, textbox

I'm trying to make a program that prints to a scrollable textbox. The only problem is that I want a delay between the characters. I've seen it using the print method but when I try to replace it with a textbox and insert it doesnt do anything. Here is the code using the print method.

```
from time import sleep
import sys
output = 'Hi... I just wanted to know if you like steak?'
for char in output:
    sys.stdout.write ('%s' % char)
    sleep (0.1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tkinter widgets have a method named `after` which you can use to run a command in the future. You can set up a function that inserts one letter, then calls itself again after a day.

I don't know what you mean by a "scrollable textbox" since tkinter doesn't have a "textbox" widget. There is a single line `Entry` widget and a multiline `Text` widget, both of which are scrollable. Here's an example using the `Entry` widget:

```
import Tkinter as tk

def insert_slow(widget, string):
    if len(string) > 0:
        widget.insert("end", string[0])
        widget.xview("end")

    if len(string) > 1:
        widget.after(100, insert_slow, widget, string[1:])

root = tk.Tk()
entry = tk.Entry()
entry.pack()

insert_slow(entry, "Hi... I just wanted to know if you like steak?")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorry by textbox i just meant text

Comment: I have another question How would i change and edit this widget. Like if i want to change the mount of lines or change the foreground color.

Comment: And also how would I add more text on a new lone when trying it would merge the lines.